# What is the purpose of storing custom data on HTML data attributes?

Tags: html, attributes, custom-data-attribute

I've been trying to understand "Why do custom data might be needed in an HTML tag? And why does it stored in `data-*` attributes?". Is it used mostly when there is no database, no API? Or is it irrelevant?.

I understand that data attributes can be used for storing the information that can't be in `class`, `id` and can be used in CSS or JS but what could be the case for storing it in an HTML tag? I'm trying to figure out the best possible right way to use custom data and data attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One use case I currently used was I created a component in react and used pseudo elements to take data from data attribute ie. data-title value will be taken by CSS in content: attr(data-title) so what ever value I am passing to component shows directly via css and also there are so many use cases for eg you need some value to be instead of passing whole object on click function you just add click event and it will take values from data attributes instead.

These two use cases I can think of rite now.

----------- UPDATE ---------------

data-* attributes allow us to store extra information on standard, semantic HTML elements without other hacks such as non-standard attributes, or extra properties on DOM, hacks can make your HTML invalid in many cases or create unknown bugs. Common attributes that we use are class, id etc and for custom attributes you can use data-*. The main motivation behind introduction of data attribute is to allow us to store extra information on standard, semantic HTML elements without other hacks such as non-standard attributes, or extra properties on DOM. So when you ask what's better approach you, all you can think about is there are multiple ways to achieve same thing and it's subjective to developer to take approch.

Comment: As I use react, I also searched for that and it says: "We don’t encourage you to keep data in DOM attributes. Even if you have to, data- attributes are probably a better approach, but in most cases data should be kept in React component state or external stores."

Comment: So, this saying makes it more confusing as I directly think of hardcoded values of the attributes

Comment: What might make it a better approach, is it being simpler, faster, more readable, etc.? So it's being hard to distinguish for me to whether I should use it or not :/